# Accord.Imaging BagOfVisualWords Object load, deserialization issue from old framework version

Tags: c#, .net, accord.net

I am using Accord.Net (version 3.7.0.0)  with C#, VS 2013 (Premium) .Net Framework v4.7+

I am upgrading from an older Accord.Net version 3.0.2.0 where I had saved/serialized to files BagOfVisualWords objects (e.g. Using BagOfVisualWords.save(sting bowFileName)

In reloading the files with the update Accord.Imaging version using the deprecated BagOfVisualWords.load(bowFileName) or the newer Accord.IO.Serializer.Load(bowFileName)
I receive the following error:

Impossible to convert object from type 'System.Double[,][] to type System.Double[][][].

I've tried using stream also but the problems seem relative to object conversion from old to new version types.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked maybe there is a problem of your VS 2013 ?

Comment: VS should be fine, I started a new solution, project from scratch and am just trying to read older versions of the saved BagOfVisualWords files. The same method calls work fine if I am loading/Saving in Accord.Net v3.7.0.0, but I only have problems when trying to deserialize from the older version 3.0.2.0.